# Implementing redux-tooltip and react-simple-maps with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm struggling to apply the same kind of setup seen [here](https://github.com/zcreativelabs/react-simple-maps/blob/master/examples/with-redux-tooltip/pages/index.js) to my React app. I have a redux store set up using combineReducers, and I'm trying to inform the Tooltip component about the information in the tooltip redux state. However, I'm not quite sure how to do this. I think I need to do something like useSelector and bring in the tooltip state, and then use useState() to actually assign it, but doing this doesn't provide the right result. Part of the problem is the example uses the next-redux-wrapper HOC, and I'm not quite sure how it's interacting with the component and its state.

Here's my component showing the map:

```
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import {
      ComposableMap,
      ZoomableGroup,
      Geographies,
      Geography,
      Markers,
      Marker
    } from "react-simple-maps";
    import { scaleLinear } from "d3-scale";
    import { Tooltip, actions } from "redux-tooltip";
    const Detail = props => {
  const exposureScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, props.val])
    .range(["white", "#f39c12"]);


    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { show, hide } = actions




  const tooltipState = useSelector(state => {
    return state.tooltip.default
  }); // I THINK I NEED TO PASS THIS TO THE COMPONENT STATE...
```

...

```
        <ComposableMap ref={container}>
          <ZoomableGroup disablePanning={true}>
            <Geographies geography={json} disableOptimization={false}>
              {(geographies, projection) =>
                geographies.map((geography, i) => {
                  if (dict[geography.properties["Alpha-2"]] === undefined) {
                    dict[geography.properties["Alpha-2"]] = 0;
                  }

                  return (
                    <Geography
                      key={i}
                      geography={geography}
                      projection={projection}

                      style={{
                        default: {
                          fill: exposureScale(
                            dict[geography.properties["Alpha-2"]]
                          ),
                          stroke: "#607D8B",
                          strokeWidth: 0.75,
                          outline: "none"
                        },
                        hover: {
                          fill: "#607D8B",
                          stroke: "#607D8B",
                          strokeWidth: 0.75,
                          outline: "none"
                        },
                        pressed: {
                          fill: "#FF5722",
                          stroke: "#607D8B",
                          strokeWidth: 0.75,
                          outline: "none"
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                  );
                })
              }
            </Geographies>
          </ZoomableGroup>
        </ComposableMap>
        <Tooltip />

      </div>
```

And my reducers/store:

```
import { reducer as tooltip } from "redux-tooltip"

const initialState = {
    title: "With Redux Tooltip",
  }

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    other reducers...,
    tooltip
})



const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    ));

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The error I'm currently getting when I try to include the Tooltip component is caused by the get() method that's part of the Tooltip component. It's clearly looking for information about the state, and I can't work out how to pass it down. Here's the error:

```
    var Tooltip = function (_Component) {
  _inherits(Tooltip, _Component);

  _createClass(Tooltip, null, [{
    key: 'displayName',
    get: function get() {
      return 'Tooltip';
    }
  }, {
    key: 'propTypes',
    get: function get() {
      return {
        // Props from state tree
        show: _react.PropTypes.bool.isRequired, // THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR - show is part of the state
```

If anyone could help me see how to give the tooltip access to the tooltip redux state (which is available on the overall state tree because it's nested inside a provider) I'd really appreciate it. I'm still fairly new to Redux and to hooks so I might be making some(many) rookie errors. Many thanks.

EDIT:

Looking at the get() method, default props are assigned, so I'm a bit stumped about what the issue is...